# How to make ForEach-Object start counting from 1 instead of 0

Tags: powershell, foreach, azure-powershell, foreach-object, powershell-az-module

I have a nice string that looks like this:

```
Get-Azsubscription | ForEach-Object {"$($a).) $($_.Name)"; $a++}
```

It allows me to count how many subscriptions I have on Azure and it adds a number to it. The problem is that the counter starts from 0, which is in my case `.)` :

[image]

How to make that counter start to count from `1` and not from `0`?

Comment: I'm assuming `$a = 1` was actually defined outside the loop and not how you have it in your code rn

Comment: Not sure of what you want actually, `(Get-AzSubscription).Count` gives you the number of subscriptions

Comment: So the title of the post isn't right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet takes an additional `-Begin` block you can use to initialize any variable you want to use:

```
Get-Azsubscription | ForEach-Object -Begin { $a = 1 } -Process {"$a.) $($_.Name)"; $a++}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73746000/45375):

Indeed you should *explicitly initialize* your `$a` variable with the desired starting value.

If `$a` is uninitialized, as it was in your case:

- Using it inside an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (`"$a"`) makes it expand to the *empty string*.
- The *first time you apply `++`* to it, it is fist *implicitly* initialized (as an `[int]` with) value `0`, so that it receives value `1`. Subsequent `++` operations then perform as usual.

While using a `-Begin` block with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) in order to initialize the variable is conceptually clear, the caveat is that the variable is *not* scoped to that statement, and lives on afterwards.

Thus, the alternative is to simply initialize it *before* calling `ForEach-Object`.

You can also streamline the command a bit by incorporating the `++` operation into the expandable string, but note that you then need to enclose it in `(...)`, in *addition* to `$(...)`; the reason is that a `++` operation produces *no output* by default, except if you apply `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), to pass the value through.

Therefore:

```
$a = 0 # Initialize the sequence number
Get-Azsubscription | ForEach-Object { "$((++$a)).) $($_.Name)" }
```

Note the initialization to `0` in combination with the *prefix* version of `++`, the [increment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#the-increment-and-decrement-operators), so that incrementing to `1` and outputting that value happens on the first iteration.

---

A simplified example:

```
$a = 0 # Initialize the sequence number
[pscustomobject] @{ Name='foo' }, [pscustomobject] @{ Name='bar' } |
   ForEach-Object { "$((++$a)).) $($_.Name)" }
```

Output:

```
1.) foo
2.) bar
```

---

Finally, a perhaps **more PowerShell-idiomatic solution** that constructs *custom objects* for display, which PowerShell automatically formats nicely for you:

```
$a = 0 # Initialize the sequence number
[pscustomobject] @{ Name='foo' }, [pscustomobject] @{ Name='bar' } |
   ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ '#' = ++$a; Name = $_.Name } }
```

Output:

```
# Name
- ----
1 foo
2 bar
```